# Should the word "question" be capitalised, when referring to, e.g., "question 2"?

Tags: capitalization

I am writing a paper in which, in my answer to the third question, I have written a sentence which includes the clause:

```
", as referred to in my answer to question 2".
```

Should the word "question" be capitalised in the above sentence?  It feels as though "Question 2" is sort-of a proper noun in this context.

Of course, if I were setting the paper and listing the questions, I would always capitalise "Question 1", "Question 2", etc.  However, this would be partly because these would begin a partial sentence and so be capitalised on that basis.  This seems a subtly different situation.

Comment: Have a look at some examples (make sure the examples are otherwise well-constructed) on the internet. I'd say this is just a style choice, and you'll find both styles being used.

Comment: I agree with Edwin.  // My personal preference would be to capitalize.  Also, since this appears to be a homework assignment, I'd say, save the agonization for work you're going to publish.

Comment: @aparente001 actually not a homework assignment at all.  Just a form.

Comment: @Statsanalyst - I would capitalize.  I would use the lower case version in a sentence where I'm talking about a question in general.

Comment: I think you guys seem to making up a new rule and even Edwin's pushing it… If you're referring to a previous instance, quotation will justify the capital. Otherwise, why, exactly, should "question 2" take a capital? D'you also suggest "town 2" or "thing 2" even "person 2" should take a capital?